# How to remove/hide axes lines in Blender

Tags: objects

I'm a bit of a Blender newbie so hopefully my question is a simple one.
In some models I'm practicing with, there's lots of spiky lines.

When doing some research, I found that there's relationship lines, which can be shown/hidden from the overlays menu -> relationships line.

However, some modals also have spiky axes lines (not sure what the right naming is).
[image: example]

I found that:

- They can be disabled under the overlays menu, by pressing extras
- They can be reduced by going to Object Data Properties and changing the size from 1M to 0.1M

My question is, what are these lines called and is there another option to completely get rid of them? Sometimes I do want to show other things also part of extra, just not these lines.

Comment: Please add an example blend file to your question. It's hard to know for sure what the cause is without more detail. (Grab the URL of the question.
Go to https://blend-exchange.com/.
Select the blend file.
Add the url of the question.
Grab the url that results.
Go back to the question and edit it.
Add the new url to the bottom of the post.)

Comment: @MartyFouts the image shows exactly the lines I'm talking about, can't make it more clear than that. Hope someone knows that they are called and how to remove them.

Comment: Those are Empty objects, i can see them from the outliner, they look like a "Y" the only way  to get of them is if you delete them all or using the EYE icon to hide them. Looks like your mesh parts are inside those. take a look at the second comment to see an image reference with blue circles and arrow

Comment: They are indeed empties, but the problem is deleting them will shift the object it's attached to. Here's more info: reddit.com/r/blenderhelp/comments/len2an/i_imported_a_3d_model_into_blender_and_it_came/

I know enough for now...thanks everyone for responding.